# Retrieve absolute paths within a Rmarkdown file

Tags: r, path, r-markdown, pipeline

I built a Rmarkdwon script that is supposed to be run from every devices. In this Rmd file, I call a R script from an another folder , within a chunck like this:

```
 '''{r, code = readLines("../../lib/script.R"), eval=TRUE, echo=TRUE}

 '''
```

Here, using a relative path allows me to run the script from all devices, regardless of the device's starting file tree.

The problem is that I have another test/ folder directory that runs this Rmd script, and the relative path no longer works because I have to do 3 folder steps backwards before going to the lib/ folder.

My question is how to get the absolute path in a variable, to call it in the chunk section?

If this is not possible, do you know a workaround?

Comment: I had good experience using the {here} package in Rmd files and call `readLines(here::here("lib/script.R")` but you need to specify the path from your current working directory so `"lib/script.R"` might not be enough.

Comment: @TimTeaFan Thanks for pointing out this option. Indeed, here::here() returns /bla/blo/blu/../../lib/script.R, so the problem is the same. The here() package always seems to be linked to relative paths, so I ended up redoing the file tree, so I could have my R script in the same folder and call it directly with here::here('script.R')

Comment: In my case the output of `here::here()` generates full path names. I think if the file is correctly targeted pointing from the working directoring it should work.